# How to automatically toggle a command off - discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm currently working on a discord.py raid-detection system, which contains this block of code:

```
raid_protection = 'Offline'
@bot.command()
async def raid_mod_on(ctx):
    global raid_protection

    raid_protection = 'Online'
    print('Raid moderation systems online')
    return raid_protection
```

I also have:

```
@bot.command()
async def raid_mod_off(ctx):

    raid_protection = 'Offline'
    print('Raid moderation systems offline.')
    return raid_protection
```

Now, I want the `raid_mod_on` command to trigger on once activated (either when called by the on_member_join event, or when called using the prefix by a user) to toggle on (return raid_protection = 'Online') and stay like that for a certain duration (for the sake of example, let's say 24 hours) before toggling back off (return raid_protection = 'Offline') automatically without any intervention.

I've tried things like `await asyncio.sleep(86400)`, but that tends to block out any async code following the call; I've also tried `time.sleep(86400)`, but that tends to also block my ordinary - synchronous code following the call.

I would like a method which is easy to implement, doesn't block any code following the function call; and most importantly: works.

All help will be greatly appreciated :)

Please do mind that I am new to Python, so showing code along with helpful suggestions is preferable for me; since I'm still learning.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This creates an asynchronous command which does not affect any other command.

But if you want you can also use `tasks.loop` Unfortunately you have to use a sleep command in both the scenarios

```py
#using asynchronous command 
raid_protection = 'Offline'


async def turnoff(ctx):
    await asyncio.sleep(86400)
    await raid_mod_off(ctx)

@bot.command()
async def raid_mod_on(ctx):
    global raid_protection

    raid_protection = 'Online'
    print('Raid moderation systems online')
    bot.loop.create_task(turnoff(ctx))
    return raid_protection


@bot.command()
async def raid_mod_off(ctx):
    global raid_protection
    raid_protection = 'Offline'
    print('Raid moderation systems offline.')
    return raid_protection
```

```py
#using tasks.loop
from discord.ext import commands,tasks

raid_protection = 'Offline'

tasks.loop(seconds=1)
async def turnoff(ctx):
    await asyncio.sleep(86400)
    await raid_mod_off(ctx)
    turnoff.stop()

@bot.command()
async def raid_mod_on(ctx):
    global raid_protection

    raid_protection = 'Online'
    print('Raid moderation systems online')
    turnoff.start(ctx)
    return raid_protection


@bot.command()
async def raid_mod_off(ctx):
    global raid_protection
    raid_protection = 'Offline'
    print('Raid moderation systems offline.')
    return raid_protection
```

Comment: Thank you, it works beautifully. I never knew about the create_task bot event - but now I'll be using it whenever I can.

Comment: No problem buddy. Good Luck with your bot!